# Flutter 'child' and 'duration' parameter aren't defined

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why in Positioned widget, I get an error that child parameter isn't defined as well as in AnimatedContainer the 'duration' parameter isn't defined.

I checked the official documentation first, but don't know why it's not working.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

```
class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  var selectedCard = 'WEIGHT';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7A9BEE),
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text('Details',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.white)),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 82.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.transparent),
            Positioned(
                top: 75.0,
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(45.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(45.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100.0,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
            Positioned(
                top: 30.0,
                left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 100.0,
                child: Hero(
                    tag: widget.heroTag,
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(widget.heroTag),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                        height: 200.0,
                        width: 200.0))),
            Positioned(
                top: 250.0,
                left: 25.0,
                right: 25.0,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(widget.foodName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(widget.foodPrice,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                color: Colors.grey)),
                        Container(height: 25.0, color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                        Container(
                          width: 125.0,
                          height: 40.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                              color: Color(0xFF7A9BEE)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                      color: Color(0xFF7A9BEE)),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.remove,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text('2',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                      fontSize: 15.0)),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Color(0xFF7A9BEE),
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 150.0,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _buildInfoCard('WEIGHT', '300', 'G'),
                          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            _buildInfoCard('CALORIES', '267', 'CAL'),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            _buildInfoCard('VITAMINS', 'A, B6', 'VIT'),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            _buildInfoCard('AVAIL', 'NO', 'AV')
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:5.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0)),
                            color: Colors.black
                          ),
                          height: 50.0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              '\$52.00',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat'
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                ))
          ])
        ]));
  }

  Widget _buildInfoCard(String cardTitle, String info, String unit) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        selectCard(cardTitle);
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: cardTitle == selectedCard ? Color(0xFF7A9BEE) : Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
            color: cardTitle == selectedCard ? 
            Colors.transparent :
            Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          width: 0.75
          ),
          
        ),
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 15.0),
              child: Text(cardTitle,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                    color:
                        cardTitle == selectedCard ? Colors.white : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                  )),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(info,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: cardTitle == selectedCard
                              ? Colors.white
                              : Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text(unit,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                        color: cardTitle == selectedCard
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }

  selectCard(cardTitle) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCard = cardTitle;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I just copied your code and built it, i got no error with the positioned widget or the animated container. in which line are you getting the error? or is it appearing in every positioned?

Comment: which version are you running?

Comment: Im running flutter version 2.2.0 on windows

Comment: Can't get it to work, not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, for some reason I didn't have my Flutter SDK path specified:

1.) Go to Settings

2.) Search Flutter

3.) Click Flutter under Languages & Frameworks

4.) Add you Flutter directory to path, in my case C:\flutter

5.) Apply & OK, Restart IDE